# How to check if a data item is empty in Blueprism

Tags: automation, blueprism

I want to check if a data item is empty or not. I am storing some values from clipboard into a data item and want to check if data item is empty or contains some text.

Comment: Forgot to mention, i want to implement a decision stage which can check if the data item contains some text or is empty and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have in my decision stage to check if I have different items at the same time. QueueData here is a collection I retrieve from the queue. Here is a screenshot of what I have in the decision properties. It has worked for me so far:
[image: Check if items exist]

Answer (score 2):

What I've done is determine the length:

```
(Len([Cost Centre])>0) AND
(Len([Quantity])>0) AND
(Len([Product Code])>0) AND
(Len([Unit Price])>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, in a decision stage, you do [Item]<>"". the <> is the symbol that means not equal to in blueprism "language", so basically here you are comparing the item to an empty string.

Comment: Error:

Cannot perform = operation when the right-hand value is empty

Comment: I tried the same. Doing [Item]<>"" Didn't work for me.

Comment: can you add a screenshot? what was the error message?

Comment: There was no error message, but even when the data item was empty, it acted as if data item had some text. I implemented a decision stage, which checked whether the data item is empty or has some text and branched out accordingly, but the decision stage always took the same path, no matter what was in the data item.

Comment: I added a separate answer because I wanted to post a screenshot of my decision stage properties. Obviously after a decision stage, you have to have 2 paths: Yes path that would be executed if the decision stage returns true, and a No path if it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to actually solve this, it may be a little bit of a hack, but since I couldn't find a proper expression for "null", and like some of the answers here state, just the <>0 does not cut the mustard, as you end up in "cannot perform <> operation when the right-hand value is empty".

What I did was create four data items for each field you need to check against: Product code, unit price, quantity and cost centre, I set up the initial values as "0" for each of them.

Then, after "get next item" action, do a multi-calc and set these values with the values from queue items. Now, if there would be an empty item, it will not change the value, but leave it as zero, so there's something you can check against. Then during the end of that loop, you need to remember to again do a multi calc where you set these values as zeros.

As in regards to the checking the exceptions, I used "Choice" so I was able to use more detailed exception reasons (ie. what field was actually empty), and since the process ends up in two different directions (exception / Place order), you need to do another multi calc set values as zeros on the other route also.

Answer (score 0):

I used `IsNumber([Data.Quantity])=False`. Since the format of the field is Number, comparing it to an empty text ("") does not give the right results in Blue Prism. The `IsNumber()` function checks if the value is a number. If the field is empty, it gives false.